# WPF How to remove a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, removeall

In my WPF application I have created and added a new Grid, I already know how to remove all Children from it:

```
    private void ClrScr()
    {
        for (int i = GridName.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            GridName.Children.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
```

But I have no idea how to kill the grid itself, my tries:

```
        GridName.Exit/Disable/Something; /// <--- no Idea what am I doing...
        this.Controls["GridName"].DIEEEE;
```

Sadly I have failed... I am very new to WPF, I've mostly played with WinForms... Help?

Comment: What is the parent of your grid?

Comment: have you tried ` this.Content = null;`

Comment: The problem being, what If I have 2 or more grids and want to remove just a specific ones...

Comment: Your main window cannot have more than one content. So if you have more than one grid, their parent must be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the grid using it's parent.

**e.g:** If you have three grids named `grid1`, `grid2` and `grid3` in a dock panel control named `main`, you can remove these grids like this:

```
main.Children.Remove(this.grid1);
main.Children.Remove(this.grid2);
main.Children.Remove(this.grid3);
```

Comment: Soooo, I should add a grid inside the grid so I can kill it later?... Sounds actually, quite logical to me :D

Comment: Where is the sample code to show what you mean? What should the user cast the grid's parent to in order to access the Children property?

Answer (score 0):

All the controls in WPF has parent except form. If the `Grid` you are going to delete is the first then you can do this:

```
var parent = myGrid.Parent;
Window window = parent as Window;
if(window!=null)
    window.Content = null;
```

Sometimes Grid can be child of a control which doesn't have `Content` property. If it doesn't have Content then it must have `Children` or `Items`.